# Unit test .Net Framework 3.5 project in VS 2017

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-test-runner

I have some legacy projects with test libraries.
The projects (and unit tests) target .NET 3.5.
We are using VS 2017 enterprise.

I was able to locate some nuGet packages that would allow the tests to build correctly, but Test Explorer does not see the tests at all.  I presume this is because there is no Test Adapter.

The packages I am using are:

- Microsoft.UnitTestFramework.Extensions v1.0.0.3
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.Updated v15.0.26228

Most of the packages I found would not install due to a lack of .Net 3.5 support.  Which makes some sense in 2017, but still.

**Does anyone know what Test Adapter I can use to make legacy .Net 3.5 unit tests visible to VS 2017 Test Explorer?**

Things I can't do:

- use a different version of VS
- re-target the libraries to a different framework version (they are for SharePoint 2010)
- Rewrite all the tests for a different test framework (unless there's a very straight forward translation of the attributes/asserts I could do with find and replace, as there's *a lot* of tests)

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @NickDarvey sadly I did not find a resolution for this.  We were forced to abandon the test libraries and re-create them.